# What is the best way to check if a role exist in array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have saved roles of an user in an array in db. The roles array looks like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5708a54c8becc5b357ad82bb"),
    "__v" : 2,
    "active" : true,
    "adminReports" : [],
    "created" : ISODate("2016-04-09T06:46:36.814Z"),
    "displayName" : "Admin Local",
    "email" : "admin@localhost.com",
    "firstName" : "Admin",
    "groups" : [],
    "lastLogin" : ISODate("2016-12-29T13:34:48.592Z"),
    "lastName" : "Local",
    "password" : "jYQB4vNsJLkkSveGZygN3llMMHbNkZWnnQZuaV4l0NAoOixh2JndlNFojigHz4Sus5St8loOWaKeKTtPVDwY4Q==",
    "profileImageURL" : "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
    "provider" : "local",
    "roles" : [ 
        "superAdmin", "admin","manager","user"
    ],
    "salt" : "1v/XyKlUdhNqgEBPaAPSeA==",
    "userWeeklyReport" : true,
    "username" : "admin"
}
```

When i have to check if logged in user is manager or admin then I am checking it with **indexOf** which is the right way to do it but my code does not looks good. Here is a snippet if i have to check if logged in user is either **admin**, **CEO** or **manager**.

```
if(req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1 || req.user.roles.indexOf('manager') !== -1 || req.user.roles.indexOf('CEO') !== -1){
    //some code goes here
}
```

There is a lot of indexOf and it doesn't looks good. Can anyone tell me what is the right way to do it, so that my code looks more readable.T
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use .includes instead?

Comment: Yeah I am using nodejs, so i think .includes will do the trick. Thanks @smnbbrv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array#some` to check if a `role` which is stored in an array exist in your `req.user.roles`. `array#includes` will check if the selected role exist in the `req.user.roles`.

```
if(['admin','manager','CEO'].some(role => req.user.roles.includes(role)))
```

Comment: array `includes` method may not cross browser compatible

Comment: One can always use polyfill.

Comment: @azad thanks god according to you arrow functions are supported everywhere. And the OP is operating with node.js and not browsers

Answer (score 1):

`if(req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1 //Rest of the code}` will probably never be -1 because the array contains all the roles for which you are checking.

You need to get the logged in user's role in a variable and check if the exist in the role array,For that only one `indexOf` will be enough

```
var someRoles = 'admin'
if(req.user.roles.indexOf(someRoles )){
        //some code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with ES6, Array#some() do the job

```
let matched= ["admin","manager","CEO"].some(s=> req.user.roles.indexOf(s) !== -1)
```